# Yii: model->save и непредсказуемый результат, почему?

Tags: php, yii

Когда я получаю массив из 2 моделей (`CActiveRecord`), прогоняю через `for(){}` и пытаюсь для каждой модели написать функционал на изменение значения свойства модели и его сохранения, результат поражает: вместо функционала для разных моделей я получаю функционал только для одной (первой по индексу в массиве) модели. Т.е. когда я тыкаю на кнопки для 2-й модели, изменения происходят только с первой!

Как же так?

Пример кнопок: http://s017.radikal.ru/i441/1510/c7/974e00e3f8be.jpg

```
$this->receiveList = Invite::model()->findAll( $criteria2 );    // array of 2 objects

for ( $key=0; $key <= count($this->receiveList) - 1; $key++ ) {
    // yes
    if ( isset($_POST['formInviteYes']['sendRequest']) ) {
        unset($_POST['formInviteYes']['sendRequest']);

        $this->receiveList[$key]->status = 1;
        $this->receiveList[$key]->save(false);

        $this->refresh();
    }
    // no
    if ( isset($_POST['formInviteNo']['sendRequest']) ) {
        unset($_POST['formInviteNo']['sendRequest']);

        $this->receiveList[$key]->status = 0;
        $this->receiveList[$key]->save(false);


        $this->refresh();
    }

    print('<form action="" method="post" id="">');
        print('<input type="submit" name="formInviteYes[sendRequest]" value="Согласиться"" class="inviteAnswer">');
    print('</form>');

    print('<form action="" method="post" id="">');
        print('<input type="submit" name="formInviteNo[sendRequest]" value="Отказаться" class="inviteAnswer">');
    print('</form>');
}
```

**Не знаю за что минусы фигачите, но eng-девелоперы разобрались в вопросе.**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136342/yii-model-save-unpredictable-saving

Comment: Yii 1 - это устаревший фреймворк, от которого стоит отказаться.

Comment: Слова фрилансера.

Comment: Вообще-то там уже второй yii почти год как вышел. Он, конечно, почти настолько же невыносим, но смысла использовать первый теперь нет вообще. А как к этому относится моя занятость, и с какой попытки вы ее угадаете - я не знаю.

Comment: Я пишу свой проект уже долго..) и когда начинал 2ой был очень сырой еще.. да и щас не думаю что прям высох..))

Comment: @Etki не думал, то фреймворки могут устаревать )) Я лично люблю больше Yii1

Comment: @korytoff попробуйте использовать любое приложение/фреймворк с вызовами `mysql_`

Comment: @Etki да, тут согласен. Я придерживаюсь модульной архитектуры, например как в Symfony2. Можно обновить только Doctrine

Answer (score 1):

Это потому что условие всегда срабатывает в первой же итерации!

Можно переписать как-то вот так (но, это не совсем тот подход, использование которого предполагается в Yii и другим фреймворках использующих MVC! Код как минимум должен быть разделен на views и controller)

```
$this->receiveList = Invite::model()->findAll($criteria2);    // array of 2 objects

$data = $_POST['formInvite'];

// перебор массива можно вообще упустить, все зависит от того, что хотите видеть в итоге...
foreach ($this->receiveList as $key => $inviteModel) {

    if ($data['id'] == $key) {
        $inviteModel->status = $data['answer'] === 'Согласиться' ? 1: 0;
        $inviteModel->save(false);
    }

    $this->refresh();

    echo '<form action="?" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="Согласиться" class="inviteAnswer">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="formInvite[id]" value="' . $key . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="formInvite[answer]" value="Согласиться" class="inviteAnswer">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="formInvite[answer]" value="Отказаться" class="inviteAnswer">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```